# Python - Use pandas to overwrite CSV column with list

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

So I have an Excel file with two columns, Fruit Name and Price. In the Fruit Name column, I have three variables which I want to overwrite with the following values: apple, banana, cherry.

My code is below, when I try and do this I get the error ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. Even though there is three items in the column. Can anyone help?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df['Col A'] = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```

Comment: What is `len(df)` print? Assuming this is your actual problem...

Comment: It says the length is 3, but there 4 values in that column. Header and 3 values beneath

Comment: Then you will not get a "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index." there is either something wrong with your code or your data.

Comment: Figured it out, it was a whitespace error.